# Unable to get page feeds that are shared from a facebook profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ok I get some restriction from facebook which I am unable to find in developer docs.

When I request data from facebook using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/feed?limit=1&locale=en_GB&access_token={access-token}&fields=id,from,message,link,actions,status_type
```

Everything works ok for profile. Though for a page it provides feeds, that page has created and shared from other pages, but it never returns feeds which are shared from a facebook profile.

I tried sending some other parameter in fields, but nothing works for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I think I get the answer. And it is impossible as it is a restriction from facebook API since API 2.0

I get some answers from facebook team on this. Below is the link to it:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1057965060965057